# Same async script called multiple times, Chrome downloads it only once

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a page with a script called multiple times in a page, ex:

```
<script async type="text/javascript" src="https://example.com/script?id=abc"></script>

<script async type="text/javascript" src="https://example.com/script?id=abc"></script>

<script async type="text/javascript" src="https://example.com/script?id=abc"></script>

<script async type="text/javascript" src="https://example.com/script?id=abc"></script>
```

Since the output of the script changes for each request, it needs to be downloaded every time. On Firefox it works as intended, but Chrome downloads it only once or twice, even if it has the headers

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
```

How can I do? (I can't change the `<script>` tag in any way)

Comment: `once or twice` - if it only ever loaded it once, I'd say some other cache busting techniques would work ... but once or twice? seems like chrome breaks yet another standard way of doing things

Comment: @Bravo yes, it appears to be random, 90% of the times it's downloaded twice, and it doesn't matter how many times the script is present on the page

Comment: I dummied up some code, and never managed to get Chrome to actually load more than once - still, that cache-control should do it

Comment: I guess Chrome wants to work like IE/Edge